# CodeIgniter 2.2.1 and Xampp 5.5.19 Not Connecting to Database

Tags: php, codeigniter

I was previously using Xampp 1.8.2 and CodeIgniter 2.2.1 connecting to MSSQL 2012. My database configuration was working well and fine until i moved to xampp 5.5.19 and using the same database configuration. This is how i did it:

I downloaded respective Microsoft drivers for PHP for SQL server (php_sqlsrv_5ts.dll) and copied it to the ext folder in the php installation folder. I then updated my php.ini file to load this extension. I also configured my MSSQL co listen to a specific port (is used the standard 1433). I then configured my database connection in the config codeigniter folder as follows:

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'CORE14\CORE12';
$db['default']['username'] = 'sa';
$db['default']['password'] = 'sa';
$db['default']['port'] = 1433;
$db['default']['database'] = 'HomoOpes';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'sqlsrv';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

I restarted my server and tried to access my application. I get the error:

> A Database Error Occurred
>
> Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.
>
> Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\TUMHRMS\system\database\DB_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 124

I thought xampp 5.6 was unstable and i uninstalled it because it was bringing the same problem it then installed xamp 5.5.19 and am getting the same problem. Somebody help.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use odbc driver

```
$db['mssql']['hostname'] = 'Driver={SQL Server};Server=CORE14\CORE12;Database=HomoOpes';
$db['mssql']['username'] = 'sa';
$db['mssql']['password'] = 'sa';
$db['mssql']['database'] = 'HomoOpes';
$db['mssql']['dbdriver'] = 'odbc';
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Live long Ragilliyandi Erick Putra I

Comment: And odbc is far much faster than sqlsrv!

Answer (score 0):

try to change

```
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'sqlsrv';
```

to

```
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
```

or

```
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli';
```